# How to replace/reset an element value in a TCL array?

Tags: arrays, replace, tcl

Say I have an array in a TCL, and I want to change the value of the element which has a key say "First_elem". How I can do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just set the array element like any other variable: `set myArray(key) "value"`

Here's a more complete example:

```
array set myArray {
    key1 1234
    key2 5678
}

echo $myArray(key1)
set myArray(key1) "test"   // Change an existing element
set myArray(key3) "hello"  // Add a new element
echo $myArray(key1)
```

Comment: Ok, but if it is a list (the value), can I change one elem in that list without touching the other elements of the list?

Comment: You can do that with the `lreplace` (replace an element in a list) function. This would replace the second list element of the key1-value in my example (the value has to be a list of course, which it is not in my example): `set myArray(key1) [lreplace $myArray(key1) 1 1 "hello"]`

Comment: Instead of '`lreplace` you can use `lset`. I.e. `lset myArray(key1) 1 "new value"`.

Comment: `echo`? Take your shell hat off for a minute ;) Or `interp alias "" echo "" puts`